# Appery.io - Refomatting an API return call NO mapping

Tags: arrays, datetime-format, appery.io

I am using the NOAA API to return tide data for a given location.   When I get the date/time info back (array with `predictions.t`) , it maps directly to a field in a grid using `{{prediction.t}}`. `(t=date & time)`.

I want to reformat that from UTC format (I have the TS code for that), but I cannot figure out where to put it.  There is no output mapping as the API return values go straight to a field.  The return data is usually three or four dates with this format;

> 2023-07-17 00:28
> 2023-07-17 06:31
> 2023-07-17 13:10
> 2023-07-17 18:30

I'd like those to read:

> July 17, 12:28 AM
> July 17, 06:31 AM
> July 17, 01:10 PM
> July 17, 06:30 PM

Comment: You are looking for javascript based solution to transform the dates as `July 17, 01:10 PM` format?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that you want to pass the date as 2023-07-17 00:28 and receive date as July 17, 12:28 AM. Refer the code sample below for reference:**

```js
const dates = [
  "2023-07-17 00:28",
  "2023-07-17 06:31",
  "2023-07-17 13:10",
  "2023-07-17 18:30"
];

function formatDate() {
  const options = {
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    hour12: true
  };
  
  dates.forEach(element => {
   let date = new Date(element);
   console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
  });
}

console.log(formatDate());
```

Comment: Thanks for the code SelkaN.  I tried to run this right after I make my API call but Appery.io isn't liking it.    

Getting the following error:     

Argument of type '{ month: string; day: string; hour: string; minute: string; hour12: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'